# Cómo elaborar un datepicker con angularJS material?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

Quiero traer un *datepicker* con **AngularJS Material**, al momento en que ejecuto mi código, se muestra mal, como si no cargaran los estilos:

```
<md-datepicker class="fl_input" ng-model="$ctrl.myDate"></md-datepicker>
```

Así tengo mi código **JS**:

```
class ManFormController {
    constructor($log){
        this.$log = $log;
        this.$onInit = this.onInit;
        this.myDate = new Date();
        this.isOpen = false;
    }
    onInit() {
        $("#man-form").FlowupLabels({
            feature_onInitLoad: false,
            class_focused:      "focused",
            class_populated:    "populated"
        });
    }
}

ManFormController.$inject = ["$log"];

import template from "./man-form.html";
import "./man-form.styles.scss";

angular.module('webapp').component("manForm", {
    controller: ManFormController,
    templateUrl: template,
    bindings: {
        mentor: "<",
        catalogs: "<",
        onUpdate: "&"
    }
});
```

El *datepicker* se muestra así:
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré el error era un CSS de angular-material, el problema venía en table, los td y th hice el cambio en esos estilos y funcionó de manera correcta